# Parent page spawn modal window, button on modal windw cause trigger postback on parent?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, simplemodal, modalpopups

I have a asp.net webform.
There's a few fields on the form that the user will fill out.
There is a hyperlink that opens a modal window (I'm using jquery & prettyphoto, but may switch to http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ because his documentation is better)

The modal window contains an iFrame where the user makes a selection and saves a record.

At this point I need to close that window and trigger a postback on the parent page.

Currently I have a hyperlink on the last page where the target = parent and href = the parent page url.
Then I have a javascript that autoclicks it. I know it's a cheap hack.
It then sends the user back to the parent page, however the pages is reloaded and all the original data is lost. *This is the problem.*

**What's the best way to do this?**

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parent window and the child iframe are on the same domain, then this should be fairly simple.

Inside of the iframe, `window.parent` refers to the outer `window` object, and in the outer page, it refers to itself.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent

So in the iframe, you can write code along the lines of:

```
// Check to make sure we're an iframe
if (window.parent !== window) {
  // Run an arbitrary function in the parent window
  var daddy = window.parent;
  daddy.doStuffThatSubmitsAFormInTheParentPage();
}
// Make sure you have that function defined in the parent page.
```

Here is an example of the access in jsbin. You'll need a console to see the love.

http://jsbin.com/ucisi/5

The related code if you want it pretty

http://jsbin.com/ucisi/5/edit

http://jsbin.com/ucisi/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

With Alex's solution I was able to solve this.

On the parent page, I have:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
    function clickPostBackButton() {
        document.getElementById("<%=PostBackButton.ClientID%>").click();
    }
-->
</script>

<asp:Button CssClass="hide" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Text="Postback" ID="PostBackButton" />
```

Then on the iFrame that loads in a modal window. I have a form with button. The button takes the user to another page. On this page I have this code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // Check to make sure we're an iframe
if (window.parent !== window) {
  // Run an arbitrary function in the parent window
  var daddy = window.parent;
  daddy.clickPostBackButton();
}
// Make sure you have that function defined in the parent page.

</script>
```

At this point the modal widow is closed and the parent page get a postback triggered.
It's important to note that my button has CausesValidation="false", without this my page had validation issues. Thanks for your tip Alex Sexton

Comment: I find it interesting that you list your solution as the answer, yet give credit to Alex Slexton's response. Huh.

Comment: Mike, wtf. People are looking for the actual code so they can copy and paste it and move on. The code above is just that.